# A Question Regarding Weak Diamond

Tags: set-theory, infinite-combinatorics

In Assaf Rinot's survey article "Jenson's diamond principle and its relatives", he proves the following fact:

Fact 2.5:For every stationary set S, $\Phi_{S}$...entails that no ladder system <$L_{\alpha}$| $\alpha$$\in$S> has the uniformization property.

Can one prove the converse, that is, for every stationary set S,  if no ladder system  <$L_\alpha$| $\alpha$$\in$S>  has the uniformization property then $\Phi_{S}$?  If not, why not?

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what $\Phi_S$ asserts?

Comment: I think Assaf's paper is here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.2151v2.pdf. $\Phi_{S}$ asserts, for a stationary subset $S$ of $\lambda^{+}$, that for every function $F$ from $^{< \lambda^{+}} 2$ into $2$ there exists a function $g$ from $\lambda^{+}$ to $2$ such that for every $f$ from $\lambda^{+}$ to $2$, the set $\lbrace \alpha \in S : F(f|\alpha) = g(\alpha) \rbrace$ is stationary.

Comment: I believe that in a model of $PFA(S)[S]$, no ladder system $\left<L_\alpha: \alpha \in \omega_1 \right>$ has the uniformization property while $2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1}$ (and hence $\lnot \Phi_{\omega_1}$). But I might be wrong.

Comment: @RamirodelaVega: Have you a reference?

Comment: What happened to the answer?  I made a hard copy of the reference the answer gave (thanks, by the way), went away from the computer to read through the reference and when I came back to the computer,the answer was gone.  I had some questions to ask regarding the relation between the reference and the answer, so I would like to see the answer again.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is just an elaboration of Ramiro de la Vega's comment above.  In "Chain conditions in maximal models" (which you can find [here](http://journals.impan.gov.pl/fm/Cont/fm168-1.html)) Larson and Todorcevic show that after forcing with a Suslin tree, no ladder system (on $\omega_1$) in the extension has the uniformization property.

However, there are many models for which there exists a Suslin tree $S$ such that after forcing with $S$, $2^\omega = 2^{\omega_1}$ holds, and hence $\Phi_{\omega_1}$ fails.  For instance, a model of $MA(S)$ (the forcing axiom for all ccc posets which preserve $S$) satisfies $2^\omega = 2^{\omega_1}$, and forcing with $S$ does not change this.

Comment: Paul McKenny:  Does Larson and Todorcevic's result depend in any way, shape or form on $AD^{L(\mathscr R)}$?|

Comment: No, it's a ZFC result.

Comment: Mc'Kenney:  And yet, in their paper "Locally Compact Perfectly Normal Spaces May All Be Paracompact", Larson and Tall show that (in their Theorem 3) $MA_{\omega_1}$(S)[S] implies that all Whitehead groups are free, even though $MA_{\omega_1}$(S)[S] also implies (as you point out) that $2^{\omega}$=$2^{\omega_1}$. Thus you have a situation in which $\Phi_{\omega_1}$ fails and yet all Whitehead groups are free.  Why is that?

Comment: Could one, for example, have a model of ZFC+$MA_{\omega_1}(S)[S]$+$\lnot$CH in which all Whitehead groups are free?  If not, why not?

Comment: (Perhaps the property of normal first countable spaces being "collectionwise Hausdorf" in a model of $MA_{\omega_1}$(S)[S] might have something to do with it, at least as far as $\Phi_{\omega_1}$ failing yet all Whitehead groups being free goes....)

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin: What was the problem here?  "All Whitehead groups are free" is, according to Assaf Rinot's article, equivalent to "no ladder system on a stationary set has the uniformization property."  But this is implied by $MA_{\omega_1}(S)[S]$ (according to the Larson-Tall article).

Comment: McKenny:  So $ZFC$+$MA_{\omega_1}$($S$)[$S$]+$\lnot$$CH$ is then consistent if $ZFC$ is?

Comment: Thomas: Of course! (Assuming the consistency of ZFC, of course.)  $MA_{\omega_1}(S)[S]$ implies the negation of CH, so all you need is $MA_{\omega_1}(S)[S]$, which you can get by forcing with a suborder of the standard $MA$ forcing.

Comment: So I guess the question is (for me, at least), then,  under what conditions does $MA$ kill or preserve Souslin trees?

Comment: Thomas: the full $MA$ kills all Souslin trees.  The point of $MA(S)$ is that it is the forcing axiom for exactly those ccc forcings which *don't* kill $S$.